# Allow views custom plugins on a particular filter criteria only

Tags: 7, views

I have started to create a custom views plugin to sort the fields in view according to the video views(not node views but youtube views) on my video content type.
This is how I've implemented `hook_views_data()`:

```
$data = array();

$data['post_video_views']['table']['group'] = t('PROJECT_NAME');

$data['post_video_views']['table']['join'] = array(
  'node' => array(
    'left_field' => 'nid',
    'field' => 'nid',
  ),
);

$data['post_video_views']['popular'] = array(
  'title' => t('Popular videos'),
  'help' => t('Youtube views'),
  'field' => array(
    'handler' => 'views_handler_field',
  ),
  'sort' => array(
    'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
  ),
);
```

This gives me an option to sort ascending and descending and also provides the fields to add. Everything working fine till this step.

Now, I want that this options should only appear when when I have the following filter criteria satisfied: `Content: Type (= Video)`. How can this be done? I know this should be simple to do but just don't know where to do it.

P.S: I am using Views 3 with D 7.22.

Comment: Would love to be proven wrong, but I'm pretty sure there's no existing mechanism to do that. You'd probably have to implement your own `views_handler_relationship` which adds an explicit content type condition to the join

Comment: Are you wanting this option to be presented in the UI automatically when content type video is selected, or do you want all Views with content type video to be automatically sorted by this plugin?

Comment: @Jimajamma I want this option (sort criteria) to appear in UI only when content type video is selected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hook_form_alter to add a conditional display of your filter based on the video selected option.

```
 /*
  *Implement hook_form_alter
  */

function MY_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
   //dsm($form) -> to get the form['#id']
   if ($form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-YOUR_VIEWS_NAME-DISPLAY') {
      $form['YOUR_FIELD_NAME']['#states'] = array(
       'visible' => array(
        ':input[name="THE_VIDEO_FIELD_NAME"]' => array('value' => 'THE_VIDEO_KEY'),
        ),
     );


   }
}
```

YOUR_FIELD_NAME is the field to display conditionally